# Can I replace the XScreenSaver lock dialog with the version from Gnome-Screensaver

Tags: 11.10, xubuntu, screensaver, xscreensaver

Im using Ubuntu 11.10, with XFCE and xscreensaver, the xscreensaver configurator is nice but the unlock dialog is ugly.

I tried gnome-screensaver, but it only gives me a blank screen.

So, can I have the `gnome-screensaver` unlock dialog with `xscreensaver`

Comment: do you have a second graphics output installed / enabled? I somtimes faced the issue, that the unlock dialog appears on the (not connected) second screen)

Comment: No, the default behaviour if `gnome-screensaver` in oneric is like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I share your opinion on the Xscreensaver unlock screen. However, changing it requires quite a bit of skill and dedication. Some have also offered solutions in this related post:

[How do I theme the xscreensaver unlock screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85109/how-do-i-theme-the-xscreensaver-unlock-screen)