# Replace xscreensaver locker with a better tool (sddm, gdm3) on Lubuntu (LXQt)

Tags: lubuntu, xscreensaver, sddm

Upon logging in on Lubuntu 19.04 it is using sddm, but when the computer is idle too long and it goes into idle, when I go to log back in it is using xscreensaver(which I can't stand the look of). I installed gdm3 in an attempt to change both over to a single interface, but all it did is replace sddm leaving xscreensaver as my login after idle. How can I replace xscreensaver in Lubuntu?

Comment: Why didn't you just disable screensaver (https://manual.lubuntu.me/3/3.2/3.2.20/screensaver.html?highlight=screensaver)  ; Lubuntu uses it as it's locker  (so whilst disabling it will disable all screensaver functions, the locker will remain), so switching to `gdm3` I wouldn't have expected to have impact on xscreensaver locking.

Comment: You should clarify the question:  do you want your system to lock when idle or not? do you dislike xscreensaver or any locker? (do you dislike the fact that locking is made by a separate tool than the logging-in, or do you dislike locking as such? what about lock after suspending? do you want that?); if you do want a locker, which one exactly  would you prefer?

Answer (score 5):

#### Why your solution didn't work

LXQt uses **[`xdg-screensaver`](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-screensaver.html)`lock`** to handle locking. This tool generally chooses the screensaver based on the desktop environment but `xscreensaver` takes precedence so that eliminates some other options, including `gnome-screensaver`¹.

#### The real solution

Luckily, there are others that take precedence over `xscreensaver`, including the one that trumps them all: **[`xautolock`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/xautolock)**. Technically that's not a locker, so you'd need something else. Something light like **[`xtrlock`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/xtrlock)** would do the trick (and it's super light).

Make sure you autostart `xautolock -locker "xtrlock -b"` (remove the `-b` if you don't want the screen blanked) and keep `xscreensaver` from starting:

1. Navigate to **Menu** » **Preferences** » **LXQt Settings** » **Session Settings** » **Autostart**
2. Uncheck the check box next to **Xscreensaver**
3. Click the **Add** button
4. In the **Name** field add something like "xautolock xtrlock"
5. In the **Command** field add `xautolock -locker "xtrlock -b"`
6. Click **OK**
7. Click **Close**
8. Log out and back out again

#### You can fix `xscreensaver`, too

Since your primary issue is looks, You might want to look into [theming `xscreensaver`'s lock dialog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85109/how-do-i-theme-the-xscreensaver-unlock-screen). This is arguably a much wiser solution as `xscreensaver` is really notable for its [commitment to security](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/toolkits.html), i.e. to actually work under any conditions as a locker.

---

¹ …which is not included with `gdm3`, so you didn't install another lock mechanism. If you did want this single interface, you'd need to install the screensaver as well. You'd also have to do the above except instead of `xautolock` you could use `gnome-screensaver`. I wouldn't recommend this any more than I would recommend trying to use KDE's locker (which is *not* `sddm`as it seems) since they are tightly integrated into the desktop environment and kind of useless outside of it.

Comment: I'm not talking about the screen saver, I have the screensaver disabled so I will just get a blank screen. But when I wake the computer from idle it asks for my password using the xscreensaver interface instead of the seem interface.

Comment: Ah misunderstood the problem. Revised the answer entirely.