# Run xscreensaver with gnome-screensaver lock screen

Tags: gnome, 12.10, screensaver, xscreensaver

I am running Ubuntu 12.10, and I just switched over from 11.04.

I'd like to use the xscreensaver functionality (actually, all I want is for electricsheep to run in the background after I have locked the screen), but at the same time, utilize the nicer gnome-screensaver login screen.

It seems as though gnome-screensaver should be using xscreensaver, but for some reason, I can't get it to work correctly. If I have gnome-screensaver running, it simply blanks the screen. On the other hand, if I run xscreensaver and use the xscreensaver-command --lock, then it runs the selected screensaver, but it uses the UGLY UGLY xscreensaver login prompt.

I've read the following:
[Can I replace the XScreenSaver lock dialog with the version from Gnome-Screensaver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71306/can-i-replace-the-xscreensaver-lock-dialog-with-the-version-from-gnome-screensav)

But it doesn't appear to answer the question. Instead, it simply answers that there's a hacky way of 'themeing' the xscreensaver.

Any advice on what I should do if I want a halfway decent looking login screen with some type of idle computation/display application?

Answer (score 1):

On 12.04 you can install both xscreensaver and keep default gnome-screensaver, together, despite the "warnings" about how xscreensaver won't run unless you stop gnome-screensaver (which aren't true).

If you have, in "brightness and lock" settings under system settings, the screen set to "require my password when waking from suspend", then, if xscreensaver kicked in before the computer suspended (a question of timing), you will see xscreensaver running on wakeup, and you will have to unlock xscreensaver (the ugly xfce theme), and you will then also be greeted by another screen to unlock, the gnome-screensave theme. This happens for me even if I set xscreensaver to NOT lock the screen. That's the best I can figure. You can have xscreensaver's unlock screen or both, but you can't have just gnome-screensaver's unlock, if you want xscreensaver.

Edit: After resuming from suspend that would have happened after the lock screen timeout for gnome-screensaver AND with lock screen UNselected for xscreensaver, the gnome-screensaver unlock will quickly come up to interrupt the xscreensaver and I will only have to unlock gnome-screensaver's "pretty" screen, without being bothered by the xscreensaver lock dialog even once. Sometimes.